# "A" Flagged as Dupe of "B" Which was Closed as Dupe of "A"

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

While ♫ *living it up in the CVQ,*♪ * I came across a dupe question being closed as a dupe of a question which already had an answer. I thought "Hey that's silly. I should just follow the link and propose the grandparent as the original instead of some arbitrary middle question."

So I got to the grandparent, copied the URL, and went back to the CVQ to present the better dupe. I got an error:

> questions cannot be duplicates of themselves

Reading the two questions again, it dawned on me:

[image: circle of dupes]

Should this be some sort of safeguards in place for this? As entertaining as it was, it's hardly useful. But the worst part was *anyone could have gone along with it,* since it's not plainly obvious what's about to happen. Furthermore, the user who voted to close clearly meant to go the other way, but accidentally did it this way instead. (We've since discussed it and his vote is now retracted)

At first I thought this was a geniusly diabolical audit. It's not.

### Original question:

[What do numbers starting with 0 mean in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python)
[image: original question]

### Its flagged duplicate:

[Why does this print the wrong number in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964163/why-does-this-print-the-wrong-number-in-python)
[image: duplicate]

Observe that the title of the original question, and the title of the link in the question closed as dupe are identical. Circular dupiness!

<sup>* That really should be the title of the Stack Overflow theme song</sup>

Comment: Stack-Inception

Comment: Oh don't mind this. It's just SE's version of the Portal video game. Yay! You found an SE easter egg! :D

Comment: @Geobits: I thought audits were meant to be _extremely_ obvious.

Comment: Not true! I read it enough to conclude it was an exact dupe. In fact, it was literally 100% verbatim exactly identical! Nothing is
 more dupe than that

Comment: @gnat, interesting. I couldn't find that (search terms are tricky on this one.) it certainly does appear this is a dupe. It does however seem that warning doesn't pop up anymore though? Otherwise how did I get
 this

Comment: @mhlester search term for this kind stuff is "circular" in [meta-tag:exact-duplicates] tag. Warning seems to pop up only when one casts a "final" vote, when one dupe closure already happened and another one is about to happen (a month or two ago someone observed that there can even be data race when final votes on both questions are cast almost simultaneously)

Comment: Maybe I should make a feature request that dupes must point to an older post. Or maybe there are reasons for going backwards..?